# Lightroom: Change location of PSD files

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, file-management

Is it somehow possible to move PSDs into a separate folder or to a different location besides next to the original image?

When I open an image from Lightroom into Photoshop and save that file, a .psd will be created but (as far as I see it) it is in the same folder as the original image I opened in Photoshop.

Can I change that location to have an extra folder only for .psd files? Or move that .psd and still keep the connection to lightroom?

Currently it's like this:

```
My folder
    Image_01.jpg
    Image_01.raw
    Image_01.psd
    Image_02.jpg
    Image_02.raw
    Image_02.psd
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
My folder
    Image_01.jpg
    Image_01.raw
    Image_02.jpg
    Image_02.raw
PSD (this is a folder)
    Image_01.psd
    Image_02.psd
```

I work on mac if this is important.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I doubt this is on-topic here, as it'a more about file handling than actual photography. This, though, is the same for any app… once you hand off to the file-picker dialog, the Mac will always return to the last place that app opened or saved. This is a system-level handler [though remembered per app]. Such as Default Folder X can assist in overriding that, but even with it, you'd still need almost as much manual input to achieve what you want - though you could hot-key the locations unlike with Finder alone.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. I thought I would reach more people that use Lightroom here. What stackexchange is the best for this question in your opinion?

Comment: It would fit on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest) - definitely more Mac users, though probably a lower percentage of Lr users of course.

Comment: As asked, this question about file management is not about photography, per se.

Comment: @Tetsujin, IMHO this is not for Mac, the operation can be done independently of operating system. Also here you will find much more users of LR compared to Mac community.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move all PSD files to other directory follow the next procedure:

1. Goto Library, Filter
2. In text select Filename, Ends With, write **psd**
   [image]
3. Ctrl+A (or was Option+A on Mac) to select all the files (psd)
4. From the left panel navigate to the parent directory where you want to create new directory or directly move files to existing one.
   [image]
5. In case of creating new directory do not forget to select "Include selected photos"
   [image]

Unfortunately I do not see a option to make this automatically when edit file with external program

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is, that the files aren't linked anymore. When I create a psd from a raw, they will get merged in a stack. When I move the psd to a different folder, this stack will be broken. When I just look at the raw, I will have no indication if there is a psd version of that file anywhere stored.
I think their is no real solution for this... I did a lot of researching

Comment: @skarpeta, unfortunately you should choose keep them in stack or keep them in separate folder. I am not aware of solution to link them in this case. Maybe you can post this in Adobe page as feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'Save As' option instead of the default 'Save' in Photoshop... This allows you to save your file to a different location. I believe Lightroom keeps track of the edited file as well.

Comment: Kind of. Lightroom detects it and shows it in the other folder, but there is no indication on the raw (like when I use a stack) that there is a photoshop version of this file in another folder...
I think it's not possible what I want

Comment: @bobt, this will keep two copies of the file, one original PSD, located in to the same directory as RAW, second one in to the new directory

Comment: @RomeoNinov In my test, when I started with a RAW or JPG file and did a 'Save As' after editing I ended up with a single PSD file in the new directory and no change in the original directory... I may be misinterpreting the question though.

Comment: @BobT, my understanding is LR first create psd, open in PS and on Save as store another copy